# Find all employees who live in same cities and streets as the managers

Tags: sql, postgresql

The relational database is

```
employee(employee_name, street, city)
works(employee_name company_name, salary)
company(company_name, city)
manages(employee_name, manager_name)
```

and I need to find all employees that live on the same street and cities as their manger. My code is as follows:

```
select distinct employee_name
from employee, company
where employee.city = company.city;
```

any suggestions or tips would be great.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: You query join everyone with every company in the same city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT e.employee_name
FROM  employee e
JOIN manages m ON m.employee_name = e.employee_name
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM empoloyee 
    WHERE employee_name = m.manager_name
        AND street = e.street
        AND city = e.city
)
```

Comment: @Cody If this solution answers your question, please accept the answer so that your question can be removed from the list of open questions.  Here's the guide how to accept an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers